# Which is the correct command to convert PDF files to JPEG file using Ghostscript 9.10?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm just trying to achieve what this thread tittle says. I have found several examples in Google but none of them works. Some of them return short errors while others return large ones. I think that the problem is the Ghostscript version. Is there any proven command that I can use in Ghostscript 9.10 version in order to convert a PDF file to a JPEG file???

Comment: Are you sure you mean gs 1.10 and not 9.10? And did you read the fine documentation for gs?

Comment: Sorry, and yes... it meant, 9.10.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly well for me:

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o out.jpg input.pdf
```

Without seeing your errors its impossible to know what your problem is. I really doubt you are using 1.10 (I'm not even sure that was a real version number)....

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to try that simple one. The version is 9.10. I already fixed my thread. 1.10 was a typing error. Sorry!

Comment: Also, in that command that you wrote, I don't see when you say to gs the original pdf localization...

Comment: I haven't a clue what you mean by 'localization' with respect to a PDF file. If you mean where the input PDF file goes, it goes on the end. For some reason that fell off my answer, no idea why...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Sorry, English is not my native language.

Comment: No problem, its just that localisation usually means changing language and such